# Proxy script => ReferenceError: "ActiveXObject" is not defined in <eval>

Tags: java, proxy

In my java app, I'm connecting to an url through a proxy script :

```
try {
    URL myURL = new URL("https://aaa.com");
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "policy.all");
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    BrowserProxyInfo b = new BrowserProxyInfo();
    b.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
    b.setAutoConfigURL("http://bbb.com/wpad.dat");
    SunAutoProxyHandler handler = new SunAutoProxyHandler();
    try {
        handler.init(b);
        ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(myURL);
        for (ProxyInfo p : ps) {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
    } catch (ProxyConfigException e) {
        log.error("error=> ProxyConfigException ", e);
    } catch (ProxyUnavailableException e) {
        log.error("error=> ProxyUnavailableException ", e);
    }           

    URLConnection c = myURL.openConnection();
    c.connect();

catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("error=> IOException ", e);
}
```

But when I launch the jar, i have the following error :

```
 javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "ActiveXObject" is not defined in
<eval> at line number 48
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(
NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScrip
tEngine.java:392)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornS
criptEngine.java:190)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.SunAutoProxyHandler.getProxyInfo(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.App.error(App.java:141)
        at com.App.main(App.java:81)
```

The line 48 correspond to `ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(myURL);`

Any idea of what this is ?

Comment: Your browser does not have ActiveX.

Comment: This is not a browser, i'm launching a jar through a console

Comment: I think the PAC uses ActiveX. Bad idea.

Comment: No idea, i do not have any information about it

Comment: if the PAC uses ActiveX, what is the problem ?

Comment: If the PAC uses ActiveX, the problem is that your environment doesn't support [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX). Neither does just about any other JavaScript environment anymore, ActiveX (as a web technology) is dead.